# Visual Studio 2013 Find and Replace using REGEX doesn't properly replace

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2013, find

OK, this might be something stupid that I'm missing, an unchecked box or something, but it's driving me insane, because I've done this before many times and it works, and right now it is not and I think I'm going crazy.

I need to replace all instances of a class in my files (css). The class, boxxy1, boxxy2, boxxy3, etc need to change to squary1, squary2, squary3, etc.

So what I have is:
FIND: boxxy\d
REPLACE: squary$1

Yet, when I hit find, it finds all instances of boxxy, but when I hit replace, what I end up with is squary$1 for EVERY SINGLE ONE. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose within `()` the search expression:

`(boxxy\d)` REPLACE: `squary$1`

The reason behind it is that `$1` is referring to a *Capturing Group* and capturing groups are created in RegEx using `()`

> Capturing groups are a way to treat multiple characters as a single unit. They are created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parentheses. For example, the regular expression `([0-9])` creates a single group containing the numbers from 0 to 9. The portion of the input string that matches the capturing group will be saved in memory for later recall via back references.

Comment: I knew it was something incredibly stupid, I cannot believe I didn't see it before, and I wrote it 100 times. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dalorzo has the right idea but said the wrong thing for this specific example.

For the strings "boxxy1" and "boxxy2", `(boxxy\d)` REPLACE `squary$1` would return `squaryboxxy1` and `squaryboxxy2`.

This is because `$1` is referring to the one and only capture group defined, (boxxy\d). What results is `squery$1` reevaluates to `squary(boxxy\d)`.

The correct way to do this would be `boxxy(\d)` REPLACE `squary$1`.